# Need to cut a string(Table Name) from Query in c#

Tags: string, cut

My String/Query looks like this

1. `insert into Employee Values(1,2,'xxx');`
2. `update Employee2 set col1='xxx' where col2='yyy';`
3. `select * from Employee3;`

I need to take/have `TableName` alone. Table name won't be constant it will be differed(Employee,Employee2,Employee3)  according to DB. I'm new to `C#` please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want to accomplish, please add more details along with some code example with what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Merlin I have added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of a table from a query (or in this case, a string named 'sql'), try the following:

```
        string sql = "select * from table ";
        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        int numSpaces = 0;
        char[] chArray = sql.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in chArray)
        {
            if (c == ' ')
            {
                numSpaces++;
                if (numSpaces == 3)
                    index1 = currentIndex;
                if (numSpaces == 4)
                {
                    index2 = currentIndex;
                    break;
                }
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }
        int length = index2 - index1;
        string tableName = sql.Substring(index1, length);
        MessageBox.Show(tableName);
```

Warning - this solution is based on finding the word between the 3rd and 4th space character. This limits you to have a very predictable query structure - more complicated queries may not work with this solution. Your query structure needs to be:

```
"select column_name1,column_name2,column_name3 from table "
```

Your query must not have spaces between columns and must have a space at the end aswell. Sorry for the limitations but its the best I can come up with ;)